# reduced decision making capacity with equal consequences

Tags: ethics, free-will, decision-theory

If the law determines that a category of people does not have the decision-making capacity to engage in a specific activity (such as a minor carrying a gun) than does it make sense that those same persons can and will be held legally responsible for any and all decisions made in doing so. For example a minor cannot carry a gun because they do not have the maturity and decision making capacity to do so safely. However, if a minor does access a gun and commits a crime using that gun, they will be held legally responsible for the outcome.

Comment: Minors may lack "decision making capacity" to properly handle a gun, but from quite young age they have enough capacity to understand that they are not supposed to do it. Before that age toddlers, say, are not, in fact, held legally responsible. After that minors *are* responsible, but the law is typically much more lenient on them than on adults, so the difference is still recognized.